# How to Mirror bitmap and then rotate

Tags: android, bitmap

I have bitmap which i mirror using the matrix

```
   mMirror.postScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
```

and can "un-mirror" using

```
   mMirror.postScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

However,now when I rotate the bitmap using `mRRight.postRotate(90)` , the mirroring is lost.Why?

**EDIT**
Figured a part of the answer for the.When you create a Bitmap object,an Identity matrix is used and created internally which corrects all the mirroring etc.

Now the question changes to how do I Mirror and then rotate a matrix.